# Incompatible types in initialization error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors

I've been on this for hours and can't find a solution. When I try to compile the following I get the "Incompatible types in initialization" error on the marked lines. Any help is accepted.

Here's my *Controller.m* file:

```
#import "Controller.h"
#import "Transactions.h"

@implementation Controller
- (IBAction)add:(id)sender {
    double x = [addF doubleValue];
    double bal = [balanceF doubleValue];
    double newBal = [trans add:x to:bal]; //Error marked here
    [balanceF setDoubleValue:newBal];
}

- (IBAction)sub:(id)sender {
    double x = [subF doubleValue];
    double bal = [balanceF doubleValue];
    double newBal = [trans sub:x from:bal]; //Error marked here
    [balanceF setDoubleValue:newBal];
}
@end
```

And here's my *Transactions.m* file:

```
#import "Transactions.h"

@implementation trans

-(double) add:(double)x to:(double)bal{
    return (x + bal);
}

-(double) sub:(double)x from:(double)bal{
    return (bal - x);
}

@end
```

Please tell me if you need anything else.
Thanks!

Comment: curious... how looks your Transactions.h file ?

Comment: Have you declared the add and sub methods in the Transactions header file with the same signatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'trans' is a class, so if you declare / call method using the class, and not an instance of it, they should be declared with `+`:

```
+(double) add:(double)x to:(double)bal{

+(double) sub:(double)x from:(double)bal{
```

Don't forget to change in the header file as well...

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I thought I already declared `bal` as a `double` in here: `double bal = [balanceF doubleValue];`

Comment: you did, but this is about the method modifiers, not the variables. ignore the answer before the edit, it was just wrong.